# Silverlight localization

Tags: silverlight, xaml, localization, silverlight-5.0

What are the avaliable options for translating a silverlight 5 application (Prism + MEF)?
If possible I would like to:

- not have resx files (I don't like the way they are managed)
- rather have xaml string extracted and then translated (I think there was a tool from Microsoft, that marked all XAML nodes with custom attribute and extracted the strings)
- have translations in external assemblies (in Prism they could be modules) and load them when needed
- change language at runtime

I'm open to suggestions and best practices on this topic.

edit: LocBaml is what I was talking about above, but looks like it's not avaliable for Silverlight

Comment: I'm currently using XML files (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xliff) and Data Binding to a Singleton localization source class. I could expand if you're interested.

Comment: @jv42 sure I would like to know more about your Xliff integration with SL, thanks!

Comment: Ok I'll make a short and a long description tomorrow then.

Answer (score 2):

I know this will get a number of traditional answers, but I would also like to put forward something completely original we tried (and succeeded) doing ourselves for more efficient localisation of Silverlight:

[Localisation of Silverlight projects after completion](http://blog.hitechmagic.com/?cat=23)

It basically uses attached properties to provide hooks, in the XAML, for dynamic changing of localisation strings. When they are first parsed your code gets a chance to make changes to the related elements, and a language swap just means reloading the current page.

The localisation strings come down from a server database using a simple RIA services call. The entries returned are simple key/value pairs for the chosen language.

This method also does not have the (quite large) overhead of the traditional binding methods you will see a lot of. We download *only* the chosen language strings when the app starts up. It also potentially allows edits/corrections to be sent back to the server (*if you can bear the overhead of an editor in the app... we did this but it was a lot of work*).

P.S. We were using PRISM, but it works as well in any Silverlight app as there are no dependencies (e.g. on Unity etc).

PPS. I will post some code snippets for this system when I get home tonight.

(Resx is so "last century")

Answer (score 1):

My current solution is using DataBinding on properties you want to localize (ie `TextBox`'s `Text`, `Button`'s `Content`, ToolTips, etc...) to a globally available string collection, in other words a Singleton. In my case, since I'm using MVVM Light, I have my `LocalizedStringCollection` exposed by the `ViewModelLocator`.

This collection is loaded from a XLIFF file (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xliff) into a `Dictionary<string, string>` that is a member of my collection.

Here is the key parts of the collection to expose the strings.

```
/// <summary>
/// A Singleton bindeable collection of localized strings.
/// </summary>
public class LocalizedStringCollection : ObservableObject, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _items;
    /// <summary>
    /// The content of the collection.
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, string> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        private set
        {
            _items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
            if (CollectionChanged != null)
                CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convenience accessor, most likely entry point.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">A localized string name</param>
    /// <returns>The localized version if found, an error string else (ErrorValue in DEBUG mode, the key in RELEASE)</returns>
    public string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Requires(key != null);
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);

            string value;
            if (Items.TryGetValue(key, out value))
                return value ?? String.Empty;

#if DEBUG
            return ErrorValue;
#else
            return key;
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

The XLIFF parsing is trivial using built-in XML support.

And here are XAML usage examples (can be more or less verbose depending on the syntax used):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedStrings[login_label], Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />

<Button ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding LocalizedStrings[delete_content_button_tip], Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
```

Hope this helps :)

I might make an article of this (with full source) if people are interested.